# Is consistency tautological?

Tags: logic, tautology

I assumed an idea is consistent with itself if it does not contradict itself, and that this is "tautological" because it can be inferred from itself and nothing else. Is that a misunderstanding of the terms?

Comment: Not clear... A system is *consistent* iff no contradiction can be deduced/derived in it. In what sense you call it "tautological" ? Tautological has the "common" meaning of trivial and in logic is a technical term: logical truth (for propositional logic).

Comment: To be consistent is a property of a formal systems; to be a tautology is a property of formulas.

Comment: so i've misunderstood the terms... neither am i sure what a formal system is as opposed to formulas

Comment: "Something" has to be consistent not only with itself but also with background assumptions (axioms), and that can not be inferred "from itself" in typical systems by Goedel's incompleteness theorem. Systems that can prove their own consistency are, in fact, inconsistent.

Comment: so nothing is consistent without background assumptions?

Comment: Mathematical logic is a mathematical discipline: definitions are important. A good textbook may help...

Comment: You need at least some logical axioms and rules of inference for any talk of inferring, and hence consistency, to even make sense.

Comment: Contradiction is the wrong word here. There are other relationships besides contradiction. The proper term would be inconsistent. A contradiction is a type of  inconsistency. It goes against what we already know or assume.  I suppose many people are hung up on contradictions because perhaps they are not taught about other inconsistencies in math. Everything is not a tautology or a contradiction. By definition a tautology must be consistent. That is, the truth value cannot possibly change from one moment to the next moment (even if they are centuries apart). There are other inconsistencies.

Comment: i'm baffled that someone downvoted this when it generated such a good answer

Comment: "We [say](https://www.csus.edu/indiv/m/mayesgr/phl4/handouts/phl4contradiction.htm) that a statement, or set of statements is logically consistent when it involves no logical contradiction" @Logikal you're coming off as somewhat strange

Comment: What do you mean I come off as strange? You do realize this is a Philosophy forum & not a Math forum correct? If you are speaking on Mathematics strictly then you should explicitly state that. All logic is not Mathematical which is why I stated OTHER CONTEXTS the same words could be used in. You are acting like the math definitions you learn are universal & apply at all times. Well sorry they don't. Context is everything. You might be taking your math stuff too literally as if nothing else exists. By the way I see no downvotes. And no it was not me even if there were. Don't think it was me.

Comment: ok well conncision is a friend anyway. cheers @Logikal maybe just the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consistency is a property of otherwise disparate logical statements. For example "The farmer always feeds me" and "Here comes the farmer to feed me" are consistent, though they mean different things. Any formal logical system must have consistent axioms (foundational assumptions) if it is to yield useful conclusions.

Tautology is a property of a single logical statement. For example "Either the farmer will come to feed me or he will not" is a tautology.

Comment: concise, understandable and helpful reply thanks